# List functions from another file in vscode for autoimport?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have *validations.js*

js

```
export const min = n => s => s > n;
export const max = n => s => s < n;
export const email = s => s.includes('@');
```

In *app.js*, when I type **e + tab**, it expands to **email** and adds an **import** to the top of the file.

**I want** to get as close as possible to this behavior.

Type **v.** shows a list of functions from *validations.js*. I pick **email** and the same as above happens. NOT **v.email** imported from a file where I have something like `export default { email, max, min }`

This would be something like filtering autocomplete suggestions by filename/package.

**Why**

Sometimes I know the name of the function I want, sometimes I want to pick from a list with the minimum amount of keystrokes possible.

Searched forums and extensions. I considered the use of macros and creating an extension, but I wanted first to know what others have tried.